# How do I open another page with a button in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

I am new to programming and I have a question. I have my main web page (boton) with three buttons and I want to create a function so that the button can open a page (pagina1 or pagina2) with Google App Script or GAS. How can I do that? I just have this, which is the structure of the buttons on the boton page.

[image]

and this is how it shows on the page

[image]

Comment: Please _paste your code_ here; don't use images.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Instead of using *"GAS"* you can use the anchor tag of *HTML*

*Like* :- here is an example - ***Google***

You need to change the website link and your button text, and BOOM!

Thanks ;)

Comment: <a href="www.google.com/"><Button>Google</html></a>

Comment: This is the code for your button

Answer (score 0):

Add the '_blank' in your script:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');">stackoverflow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Instead of using "GAS" you can use the anchor tag of HTML

Like :- here is an example - ***Google***

You need to change the website link and your button text, and BOOM!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).